# Time Elapsed and Timezones

Tags: php, mysql, time, timezone, elapsed

my problem is as following :
When I store a DateTime and then retrieve it and do some elapsed function to know how much time ago I stored that DateTime, I get an offset of about 7200 second, wich is 2 hours off.
Im in france, so I guess its somthing like GMT +2 (+1 hour +1 summer hour).

How can I fix this?
there is somthing to do with set/get timezone but im not sure how exactly to do it
Thanks for any help

I use php5.3; mysql 5.05

Comment: Maybe this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878790/php-adjusting-for-timezones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php you can use: `date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )` to set timezoen

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

in mysql, take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: I've actually fixed my problem by using date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');